# Не могу понять как работать с WebSocket и Long Polling php

Tags: php, база-данных, websocket

Извините сразу же за такие глупые вопросы.
Раньше я использовал ajax, но теперь мне нужно каждый раз прослушивать сообщения.

Задач несколько:

1. Сделать уведомление
2. Сделать график цены (для теста и для себя)
3. Сделать хоть что бы комментарий отображался у другого пользователя сразу-же как другой его напишет. Как у Stack Overflow.

С **Long Polling** - немного понятнее. Пример с уведомлениями. В фоновом режиме можно отправить например запрос с помощи `ajax`, и ждать ответа 10 секунд. На сервере мы каждый раз (что ли) в бесконечном цикле `while(true)` отправляем запрос к бд и ждем, пока не появятся новые записи именно для этого пользователя. Если ответа уже нет 10 секунд то закрываем этот запрос и с помощи `js ajax` отправляем новый и так каждый раз. Я наверное не правильно понял **Long Polling**. Точно ли так? И точно ли бесконечном цикле ждать новых записей?

С **WebSocket** - у меня дела по труднее. Я понял что он в реальном времени отправляем сообщения с сервера на клиент, или клиент на сервер. Т.е как я понял мы подписываемся на постоянное подключение. Я создал свой сервер с **WebSocket**. Подключился с помощи `js`.
Пример с комментариями. Человек на странице продукта. Купил товар, и пишет отзыв даже не узнав о продукте, и тут я не понимаю как записывать данные и что бы сервер сразу же отправлял данные на клиент другим пользователям. **1.** То ли с помощи `ajax` записывать  в бд, а на сервере с **WebSocket**.ом читать таблицу с комментариями и отправлять на клиент. **2.** Или одновременно записывать с помощи `ajax` в бд комментарий и одновременно отправлять на  **WebSocket** и он отправляет другим клиентам это сообщение. 3. Можно сразу же записывать в бд комментарий на сервере с **WebSocket** а потом после записи отправлять другим клиентам.

Я думаю вы все меня поняли. Подскажите пожалуйста, я все таки боюсь начинать что то с ними делать. И да... Я не могу найти источники, я всегда вижу только как создают чаты, но они не работают с базами данных. Хотя с **Long Polling** - я нашел пример, но я что то сомневаюсь, что каждый раз обращаться к базе данных.

Comment: Вы правильно поняли логику работы и с LongPool запросами и с WebSocket. Все ваши размышления не касаются ни того ни другого метода, вы сейчас рассуждаете как строить межпроцессорное взаимодействие, и это не имеет отношения ни к одному ни ко второму механизму общения между клиентом и сервером. При малом кол-ве пользователей действительно можно доставать базу данных постоянными запросами, при более высокой нагрузке - стоит подумать над оптимизацией, например использовать механизмы кеширования данных, использовать NoSQLinMemory хранилище.....

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков спасибо за быстрый ответ! Но вот, все таки я немного не понял. Получается мои размышление не имеют отношение к механизмам общения клиент-сервер.  А на счет оптимизации? Или все способы например у WebSocket  ни как не помогут оптимизировать?

Comment: Именно, ваши рассуждения имеют прямое отношение к общению процесс <-> процесс, но не к общению клиент<->сервер. В вашем случае придуманная вами оптимизация на вебсокетах - имеет право на существование, но ровно такое же поведение можно сделать и для лонгпула и для любого другого способа общения клиент сервер. Если ваши мысли сконцентрированы на том "как разгрузить БД" - то ваша задача сводится к тому чтобы как то уведомить скрипт что есть новые данные и только после этого скрипт лез в базу, а это именно межпроцесное взаимодействие

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков - спасибо большое!

Comment: Не советую использовать LongPolling в связке PHP+Apache. Просто потому, что для каждого соединения создаётся новый процесс. И в каждом процессе раз в секунду (если не чаще) выполняется запрос к базе, чтобы проверить, не появились ли новые данные

Comment: @xRef спасибо. Я их не использую. Я начал использовать websocket